# What would be a good way to pick cache file names for images downloaded from internet?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

What would be a good way to pick cache file names for images downloaded from internet for caching purpose to ensure that no matter what the URL is we got valid file name?

We often pick images from the net. It's often useful to store those images in temporary cache so we don't keep downloading the same image again and again.

So I suppose, I would need a cacheFileName. It should be a function of the URL. However, it must not contain special characters like :, /, &

In other words, it has to be a valid file name.

What would be the way to do so?

I can make some my self. Perhaps I can use URLEncode which seems to do just fine. However, I wonder, if there are consideration I missed.

This is the current Code I use:

```
- (NSString *) URLEncodedString {
    NSMutableString * output = [NSMutableString string];
    const char * source = [self UTF8String];
    int sourceLen = strlen(source);
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceLen; ++i) {
        const unsigned char thisChar = (const unsigned char)source[i];
        if (false && thisChar == ' '){
            [output appendString:@"+"];
        } else if (thisChar == '.' || thisChar == '-' || thisChar == '_' || thisChar == '~' ||
                   (thisChar >= 'a' && thisChar <= 'z') ||
                   (thisChar >= 'A' && thisChar <= 'Z') ||
                   (thisChar >= '0' && thisChar <= '9')) {
            [output appendFormat:@"%c", thisChar];
        } else {
            [output appendFormat:@"%%%02X", thisChar];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

It's taken from some great answer in stackOverflow which I have forgotten.

I wonder if the result of this function will always get a valid file name. Does anyone has better file name generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do proper networking, `NSURLCache` handles *caching* of images just fine automatically.

However, I got the feeling that you aren’t *really* interested in *caching*, but in (more or less permanently) *storing* images.

In that case, build a proper model for your app.

Because you don’t tell us what the images you want to be storing are for, I cannot be more helpful than this:

If you’re on iOS 5+/OS X 10.7+, you can use `NSAttributeDescription`’s allowsExternalBinaryDataStorage setting to have the `NSSQLiteStoreType` handle naming, creating, retrieving, updating, and deleting the backing files for the image data transparently on your behalf.

If you have to support older OS versions, you can still use external storage through a transient attribute. Your entity description then has to have an attribute for the name of the data-file, though. In that situation, the SHA-1 (available through the CommonCrypto framework) of the image’s data will provide for a good file name.

---

**Aside**

If you’ve found that code in an answer on Objective-C, downvote it, and delete that code above:

`-[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]`, and `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` do exactly what they (or their docs) say.

Comment: Perhaps a link on how NSURLCache handles caching of images would be great? I am interested in storing the image temporarily. Maybe a day or 2 just to speed things up. If NSURLCache does the job well, why not?

Comment: The only thing I can find is https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/CachePolicies.html and boy that's it. No sample code :( Once I got 15 points I can upvote you as well as checking.

Comment: NSURLCache is used by the HTTP protocol implementation in Foundation. Whenever you use the high level HTTP networking APIs on OS X or iOS, (and the response headers allow it) it is used without further ado. (Well, except if you set the cache policy to “don’t cache” in the request, obviously.) That also means there is no sample code because you don’t need to write any, most of the time. But like I wrote, I think you’re actually not really looking for _caching_, but for _storing_ data. And that’s a different beast, entirely.

Comment: So NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; means that the data will also be stored in hard disk? What about if I want to change the cache age? Should I make another question that you can answer? Thanks.

Comment: Well usually, you don’t want to use that method for any resource that’s not local for a number of reasons: for one, you cannot implement proper error handling. You cannot resume partial downloads, etc. In short: it’s just not a good fit for anything but a proof of concept or a quick hack. You shouldn’t use it for non-local resources in production code!

Comment: I shouldn't use dataWithContentsOfURL?

Comment: I definitely don’t say you should never use it! I _do_, however, say that it isn’t a good choice for retrieving arbitrarily large amounts data over the internet.

Comment: PS: I’d guess that `+[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` will fetch the data _uncached_ for HTTP URLs, but **I absolutely don’t know** that.